# CSS works in jsFiddle, but only partially works outside of jsFiddle + DIV question

Tags: html, css, layout, jsfiddle

I have encountered a strange problem - the exact same markup works fine in jsFiddle, but when I put it in a text file, only the header displays and the actual content is not shown.

I've seen other similar questions but they involve jQuery (which I don't use yet).

link:
http://jsfiddle.net/3BpRr/

**Edit:**

Jsfiddle for some reason has `<style type="text/css">` twice. I did that and it works.

Second question:

```
<div class="chatLine">
    <div class="chatName">John&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="chatMsg">I am very hungry.</div>
</div>
  <br />
<div class="chatLine">
```

Is there a way to place the `<br />` in the chatLine div? I'm going to need to use javascript to create/destroy chatLines.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you define doctype in the text file?

Comment: I declared doctype in the text file to the same as in jsfiddle (<!DOCTYPE html>). Looking at the source code, jsfiddle has two <style type="text/css"> tags, and applying that change works. hmm

Comment: You need to read about Doc Type Definition, http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Comment: done, but I still have to have 2 styles for it to work.. (firefox/chrome/IE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your last jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qktrv/1/

Hopefully that's what you are looking to accomplish.

**Changes:**

jsFiddle doesn't require a style tag in the CSS box so I took it out.  Also, I changed the rule that set absolute positioning on all divs and just put it on each div that needed it.  Even though it's set to absolute for almost everything, this may prevent other problems down the road.  If you want to change it back later to make a shorter CSS file, I don't see the harm in doing so, so long as you set the correct positioning on the divs that aren't absolutely positioned.

**Overview:**

Your chatLine, chatName and chatMsg divs were all positioned absolute because of that rule, which takes them out of the normal flow of the document.  In other words, they wouldn't expand the parent div.

Answer (score 3):

1. The problem is with `overflow:hidden;` property. Remove it or make the selector for it more precise as it is currently selecting all elements.
2. EDIT: The reason why putting a `<br />` at the end of the chatLine `<div>` causes things to blow up is because you're using absolute positioning. Try not to use absolute positioning except for things that actually are absolute.

Comment: 2: This is what happens when I put a <br /> at end of chatLine: http://jsfiddle.net/B5V7z/

Comment: I used position:absolute to position the header, sidebar, chatbar, etc.. I changed it to position:static for the left content, but the text still overlaps. I also changed .chatLine to position:static, but same result. 

See: http://jsfiddle.net/B5V7z/1/

Comment: Nevermind, I'll just mark this as solved and probably will never touch CSS again

Comment: It's ok to use absolute positioning for those things. But notice how you're letting ALL div's be absolutely positioned. You have to make your CSS selector more specific.